# SQL Listing multiple artists for a song

Tags: mysql, sql, join, associative

I suspect my question has a duplicate and I am sorry for that as I couldn't find what I'm looking for.
If that is the case, could you tell me where I can find that answer?

I want to manage a song library.

I have a table called `songs` :

```
song_id    song_name
====================
1          Airplanes
2          Relax
```

I have a table called `artists` :

```
artist_id    artist_name
============================
1            B.o.B
2            Hayley Williams
3            Mika
```

and to allow a song to have multiple artists, I have a table called `assoc` :

```
song_id    artist_id
====================
1          1
1          2
2          3
```

I want to `SELECT` all the entries in `songs` with the associated artists, like so :

`Airplanes => B.o.B, Hayley Williams`

`Relax     => Mika`

So far, here is what I tried :

```
SELECT `songs`.`song_name`, `artists`.`artist_name`
FROM `assoc`
JOIN `songs` ON `songs`.`song_id`=`assoc`.`song_id`
JOIN `artists` ON `artists`.`artist_id`=`assoc`.`artist_id`
```

But this is giving me duplicate entries for songs with multiple artists. Is there a way to get a new field listing the artists, say, comma separated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [*GROUP_CONCAT*](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)

```
SELECT `s`.`song_id`,
       `s`.`song_name`
        GROUP_CONCAT(`a`.`artist_name`) `artists`
FROM `assoc` 
JOIN `songs` s ON `s`.`song_id`=`assoc`.`song_id`
JOIN `artists` a ON `a`.`artist_id`=`assoc`.`artist_id`
GROUP BY `s`.`song_id`,
         `s`.`song_name`
```

Be ware of that fact it has a default limit of 1024 characters to concat but it can be increased which is defined in manual

### [Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ef7e1e/1)

Comment: Thank you `M Khalid Junaid`! `GROUP_CONCAT` does exactly what I need, I have come across that function but could not make it work. Thank you for your fast answer!